# Represent combinaison of values in optimal way C++

Tags: c++

Suppose that we have this representation of a payload :

Payload1 : 0x11 0x22 B 0x11
and B could be one of the following values : 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03

I need to check that this payload was received so I made a std::list which contains the different possible values of the Payload1 :

```
const  std::list<Payload> payload{
{0x11, 0x22, 0x00, 0x11},
{0x11, 0x22, 0x01, 0x11},
{0x11, 0x22, 0x02, 0x11},
{0x11, 0x22, 0x03, 0x11}
};
```

and then i used std::find to look if my received payload is one of the following or not, but then I realized that this value B will be used in many others payload!

```
Payload2 = B, 0x11, 0x13, 0x14
Payload3 = 0x22, 0x11, B, 0x11
..
```

I there a better way in term of performance and readability of code to handle this situation?

Comment: `std::list` is a terrible container to use if you are planning to look up values.

Comment: Thank you for response, so you suggest, that I could use another container like std::vector and continue with the same concept ? or you have a better idea then just storing the values in this way

Comment: There should be commas separating the individual values – or how does your Payload constructor look like?

Comment: It will depend on your actual use case, which from your description I don't really understand, but `std::unordered_set` would be a good container for unique items with fast lookup.

Comment: @Aconcagua yes you are right, suppose that the payload is just an std::vector<std::uint8_t>, I will edit the code and add commas

Comment: I think I don't get you actual problem, especially the second part. Depending on your use case payloads can usually be represented as a bit string and you can do look-ups pretty fast using bitwise operations. I think you should isolate your real problem and rephrase the question.

Comment: How many different valid payloads do you actually accept? How much do they differ? The four you provided could be checked with a few `if`s more easily...

Comment: @Aconcagua, I could have more then 20 payloads, each one of them I should handle it in differnet way, and each one of them could have different representations as shown in the example in the description,

Comment: so I need to check first which one of them is received, and to do that I should look for every possible representation of the payload, I hope the problem is more clear now

Comment: You don't need to generate each possibility for your "validator" a `return data[0] == 0x11 && data[1] == 0x22 && isPossiblyaB(data[2]) && data[3] == 0x11;` seems to do the job. (you need a `std::vector<Validator>` for the different `Payload`).

Comment: Byte search algorithms can be very complicated. Wanting both better performance and better readability might be conflicting goals.

Comment: I don't understand the question, especially the "then I realized that this value B will be used in many others payload" part, or "I could have more then 20 payloads, [...] and **each one of them could have different representation**".  Wouldn't a different representation constitute a different payload? Why don't you provide us with a complete example? Also, if you have a working implementation and you are just asking for better performance or readability or maintainability, you may ask over at codereview SE.

Comment: `std::unordered_map<PayLoad, XYZ>` could be of interest, where `XYZ` is a function pointer, member function pointer or pointer to a polymorphic handler type: `if(auto entry = lookupMap.find(payload); entry != lookupMap.end()) { /* execute entry->second */ }`.

Comment: By the way: If payload length is always four, I wouldn't use a `std::vector` for (as you mentioned in a comment), rather a `std::tuple` or a custom struct – or possibly even a `uint32_t` would do the trick.

Comment: Hm, maybe a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is an interesting alternative, too?

Comment: @Aconcagua YES ! a trie is really an interesting alternative, Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, the best a CPU can do is to treat the payload as a single `uint32_t` so the check can be implemented as `(x & 0xFFFFFCFF)==0x11220011`. That's about two instructions, but it critically depends on the range of B.

For other payloads with the same range, the CPU would just need different constants.